# SFML won't open a window?

Tags: c++, c, sfml

So, as the title suggests, I am trying to create a simple Window using **SFML 1.6** in **CodeBlocks** (MinGW v.4.7.0) on **Windows 7** (no, I'm not using an ATI GPU).

This is the code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 16), "SFML Window");
    App.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to run this code, it just says `Program.exe is not responding` and has to be shutdown using `Close this program`. The funny thing is, the first tutorial offered on the SFML tutorial website (the one utilizing `sf::Clock` in a console) works, so the libraries are loaded properly.

Can someone help me find the cause of the error I'm getting?

Other than the crash, I get no compiler or application errors.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you just started you should probably update to SFML 2.0.

Comment: Oh, it said 1.6 is the current version, so I just used that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't created the main loop which polls for events and handles OS messages. Append this to `main()` (yes, this is a snippet from the SFML documentation):

```
while (App.IsOpened())
{
   // Process events
   sf::Event Event;
   while (App.GetEvent(Event))
   {
      // Close window : exit
      if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
         App.Close();
   }

   // Clear the screen
   App.Clear();

   // Put your update and rendering code here...

   // Update the window
   App.Display();
}
```

It is therefore not necessary for you to call `App.Display()` after you create the window.

Comment: Says "sf::Window is undefined" and no dice after that, even after removing it.

Comment: I had to compile the libs myself in order to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want the whole thing, this is a snippet extracted from the [SFML website](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php#bringing-the-window-to-life).

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

You will get:

[image]